# Python desvio condicional

Tags: python

Fiz esse código, porém não compila. Estou usando **Visual Studio 2015**.

```
# Exercicio Python 2.6
import utf8

#PROGRAMA TESTE DOS IFS

#Usando Coding para assento nas Strings

input ("Digite valor de A ")
input ("Digite valor de B ")
input ("Digite valor de C ")
#TESTE
if (a > b):
    if (a > c):
         print("valor maior que A  " .a)
    else:
         print("valor Menor que A  " .c)
         # Else sempre tem que ter os : como assentuacaoo final
else:
    if (b > c):
    print("O maior valor B  ".b)
else
    print("O maior valor C  ".c)
```

Comment: E qual é o problema apresentado? De cara dá pra ver que ele não faz o menor sentido.

Comment: Tens o código com as indentações muito confusas e dão aso a mal entendidos. Para além disso as concatenações não estão corretas, não é com ponto que se fazem em python

Comment: Sugiro que descreva melhor seu problema. Eu negativei a pergunta, porque não dá pra entender qual é o problema real por trás dela.

Answer (score 6):

### Sintaxe

Vamos primeiro começar com os erros de sintaxe.

```
import utf8

input ("Digite valor de A ")
input ("Digite valor de B ")
input ("Digite valor de C ")

if (a > b):
    if (a > c):
         print("valor maior que A  " .a)  #(1)
    else:
         print("valor Menor que A  " .c)  #(2)
else:
    if (b > c):
    print("O maior valor B  ".b)          #(3)
else                                      #(4)
    print("O maior valor C  ".c)          #(5)
```

1. A linguagem Python permite que você utilize qualquer número de espaços em branco para indentação, desde que seja constante em todo o seu código. Isto é, se em um local você utilizar 4 espaços (recomendado pela [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)), todas as indentações no código deverão ser de 4 espaços. Em `#(1)` e `#(2)` a indentação possui 5 espaços, o que gerará erro.
2. A linguagem Python utiliza a indentação como delineadores de blocos lógicos. Ou seja, enquanto a linguagem C, por exemplo, utiliza os caracteres `{}` para definir o que está dentro de um bloco condicional, o Python utiliza a indentação, portanto em `#(3)`, `#(4)` e `#(5)`, uma indentação de 4 espaços será necessária. Ainda, em `#(4)` faltou um `:` após o `else`.

### Semântica

Agora aos erros semânticos (isto é, o código está completamente formatado conforme os padrões do Python, mas não funcionará por erros lógicos).

```
import utf8                               #(6)

input ("Digite valor de A ")              #(7)
input ("Digite valor de B ")              #(8)
input ("Digite valor de C ")              #(9)

if (a > b):
    if (a > c):
        print("valor maior que A  " .a)   #(10)
    else:
        print("valor Menor que A  " .c)   #(11)
else:
    if (b > c):
        print("O maior valor B  ".b)      #(12)
    else:
        print("O maior valor C  ".c)      #(13)
```

3. A biblioteca `utf8` em `#(6)` não é nativa do Python - e eu, particularmente, nunca ouvi falar de alguma com este nome. Se for realmente uma biblioteca, garanta que a mesma está devidamente instalada e na mesma versão do Python que está executando. Se a intenção é apenas declarar a codificação utilizada no código, utilize o cabeçalho `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`. Leia mais na [PEP 263](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/).
4. Em `#(7)`, `#(8)` e `#(9)` você utiliza a função `input` para solicitar ao usuário valores de A, B e C. Problemas:

   4.1.  Mesmo que o usuário informe os três valores, os mesmos não são armazenados em lugar algum. Você deve, caso queira utilizar o valor informado, armazená-lo em uma variável.

   4.2.  Não é recomendado o uso da função `input` nas versões 2.6 e 2.7 do Python. O ideal é utilizar `raw_input` e converter o valor para inteiro após: `int(raw_input("..."))`.
5. Em `#(10)`, `#(11)`, `#(12)` e `#(13)` você efetua a concatenação de strings com o caractere `.`. Acredito que este seja o padrão da linguagem PHP. Em Python, utiliza-se o operador `+` ou faz-se a formatação da string. Se fizer a concatenação, tome os devidos cuidados com o tipo da variável, pois não será possível concatenar uma string com um número inteiro.